# How to use sealed classes with generics in kotlin`

Tags: kotlin, generics, sealed-class, kotlin-sealed

I have the following classes but I'm struggling with generics

```
sealed class Result<T,E> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T): Result<T,Void>()
    data class Failure<E>(val error: E): Result<Void,E>()
}


fun interface SeqListener<T,E> {
    fun onComplete(result: Result<T,E>)
}

abstract class Seq<T,E> {

    var started = false
        private set

    var complete = false
        private set

    private lateinit var seqListener: SeqListener<T,E>

    fun start(listener: SeqListener<T,E>) {
        if (!started) {
            seqListener = listener
            started = true
            return doStart()
        } else throw IllegalStateException("cannot call start on a sequence more than once")
    }

    fun success(result: Result.Success<T>) {
        complete(result)
    }

    fun fail(result: Result.Failure<E>) {
        complete(result)
    }

    private fun complete(result: Result<T,E>) {
        if (!complete) {
            complete = true
            seqListener.onComplete(result)
        } else throw IllegalStateException("cannot call success or fail multiple times")
    }

    abstract fun doStart()
}
```

but the compiler complains that the calls to: `complete(result)` for fail/success above are of the wrong type `Required: Result<T,E> Found: Result.Success<T>` for the one from success.

If I change the `complete` method to: `complete(result: Result<*,*>)` then those errors go away but the call to `seqListener.onComplete(result)` fails with `Required: Result<T,E> Found: Result<*,*>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Off-topic, but `IllegalArgumentException` is not the right type of exception to throw here (as the arguments are _fine_ when you are throwing it) - I'm not a Java/Kotlin expert, but I think you should be throwing `IllegalStateException` instead.

Comment: Also, Kotlin has a built-in `Result<T>` type already: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/ - why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your types as `out` and use `Nothing` for the unused ones. This will make the compiler very lenient about acceptable upcasting.

The `Nothing` type can be thought of as the opposite of `Any`, because it is logically treated as a subtype of everything. So with covariant `out` types, it can be implicitly upcast to anything.

```
sealed class Result<out T, out E> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T): Result<T, Nothing>()
    data class Failure<E>(val error: E): Result<Nothing, E>()
}
```

Comment: If I'm using out T and E then I get compile issues with using these parameters as inputs to a function.

Comment: It works OK with your example Seq class above. Maybe you can add an example of how it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show me how the rest of the code changes? It's not compiling for me.

Comment: Wait sorry it seems to work now.. Strange..